# Python: Changing Values in a Dictionary Tree Structure

Tags: python, dictionary, reference, tree, dereference

I have a tree structure in Python where each node is a list [dict,int]. The dict points to the children. The leaves are plain ints, no lists to save memory. Now I want to scale the integer value in each node by a constant factor. I have written the following recursive function that takes the root node and the factor:

```
def scale(node,factor):
    if type(node) != list:
        node *= factor;
    else:
        node[1] *= factor;
        for key in node[0]:
            scale(node[0][key],factor);
```

I have the impression that the leave nodes are not changed because of some of these Python reference/dereference issues. Is this true?

Comment: Have you tested it to find out? Why not look for evidence to support your *"impression"*?

Comment: I have a normalization constraint that the sum of all child node ints is the int of the parent node. This constraint is met before but not after scaling. If I did the math correctly it should be met in both cases. And the problem seems not to occur in higher levels of the tree.

Comment: Add some `print` statements to both branches of the `if` statement. When you run the program that would show you what happens.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including data, so that others can replicate the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement doesn't do what you think:

```
node *= factor
```

This only multiplies the local variable `node`, it won't modify the dict value you originally passed in.  Ints are immutable, so there is no way to pass one into a function and have the function modify it in-place.

This article has details on how names and values work in Python: [Facts and Myths about Names and Values in Python](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

BTW: the best way to check a type is (if you must) is:

```
if not isinstance(node, list):
```

Answer (score 1):

This snippet explains why the leaf nodes (type int) are not updated:

```
def f(x):
    print "got x", x
    x *= 10
    print "set x to", x

>>> n = 123
>>> f(n)
got x 123
set x to 1230
>>> n
123

>>> l=[1]
>>> f(l)
got x [1]
set x to [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> l
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

So you can see that `n` is not changed because only the local variable `x` is updated in function `f(x)`. However, the list `l` is updated because it is mutable.

Any easy way to fix this is to wrap your leaf nodes in a `list` (or other mutable type) and store (and update) the leaf value. Then you can write `scale()` like this:

```
def scale(node,factor):
    if len(node) == 1:   # leaf node is a list containing a single int
        node[0] *= factor;
    else:
        node[1] *= factor;
        for key in node[0]:
            scale(node[0][key],factor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not going to change my data structure, I had to do the following (in my opinion this is one of these cases where Python sucks):

```
def scale(node,factor):
    for key in node[0]:
        if type(node[0][key]) != list:
            node[0][key] *= factor;
        else:
            node[0][key][1] *= factor;
            scale(node[0][key],factor);
```

And then change the root int separately before calling the recursion. Fortunately, in this case there might be the extra benefit that this should be faster because there is no function call for leave nodes...